# Amortized Time Complexity deque

Tags: stack, queue, time-complexity, deque, amortized-analysis

I need to analyze the amortized time complexity of a simple deque using 3 stacks, I need to use the potential method but I am having troubles finding the potential function.
The use is very simple (probably not efficient but whatever):

```
PushTop : enters stack1
PushBottn: enters stack3
popTop: the queue is not empty
if isEmpty s1
   if is Empty s2
     move from s3 to s1
    move from s2 to s2 
popS1

poshBottom: the queue is not empty
if isEmpty s3
   if is Empty s2
      move from s1 to s3
   pops2
pops3
```

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: `move from s2 to s2` is a no-operation, and that statement has a confusing indentation. The algorithms do not seem correct. In either pop algorithms the statement `move from s3 to s1` is not going to change that s2 is empty; yet you pop from it afterwards...